# Can I use a template to get automatic conversions between QString and std::string?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I'm wondering whether it would be possible to create an automatic conversion between `QString` and `std::string` so I can write something like this:

```
QString a, b;
std::string c, d;

a = c;
d = b;
```

and the `a = c;` and `d = b;` work as expected.

I'm thinking this is doable with templates, but it looks like all the example I'm finding only work with binary operators.

FYI, I already have the code for the implementation. What I'm really interested in is to get the assignment (`=`) operator to work. Because writing the following is tiresome and many people tend to forget and skip on using the proper conversion:

```
a = QString::fromUt8(c.toUtf8());
d = b.toUtf8().data();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment operator must be implemented as member function (see eg [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)), thus

```
QString a, b;
std::string c, d;

a = c;
d = b;
```

won't work. Instead you might want to consider a free function, something along the line of

```
assignStrings(a,c); // or perhaps... a = toQString(c);
```